# What does Path=.. mean in Silverlight Databinding?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

In DataBinding in silverlight, I notice that Path is set to .. in xaml. 
What does that mean?

Comment: Can you be more specific or maybe provide some code? I did not understand the question.

Comment: The shorthand way is to specify the binding property immediately after the 'Binding' key word without the 'Path='.  See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189022(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: `Path=..` is not valid.  `{Binding Path=.}` is exactly equivalent to simply `{Binding}` (ie, bind to the current data context).

Comment: That is, unless someone has invented some kind of magical markup extension ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name.Age.ID}"/>
```

You're saying that the data context of the TextBlock has a property called Name, which returns an object that has a property called Age, which in turn has a property called ID. The value returned by ID is what will be shown in the TextBox.

For example, if your classes looked like this and the data context for the TextBox was an instance of Foo, you'd see "Hello World" displayed:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo1 Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Foo1
{
   public Foo2 Age{ get; set; }
}

public class Foo2
{
   public string ID{ get { return "Hello World"; } }
}
```

The "." syntax just lets you refer to "subproperties" of an object. For more information, take a look at this MSDN article.

[Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)